# vim regex - match any number of whitespace at end of line except 2

Tags: regex, vim

I want to write a fixer for ale to remove all whitespace at the end of a line except for a double whitespace - in markdown this is used to create a linebreak.

I need to match "at end of row, 1 or more white space AND not 2 white space"

kind of like `\s\+$\&\s\{^2}$`  except that `^` is not negation inside curly brackets. Some googling reveals that negating a count of a meta character seems to be a particularly niche problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
:%s/\v(\s)@<!\s(\s{2,})?$//g
```

*Details*

- `%` - search on all lines
- `s` - substitute
- `\v` - very magic mode
- `(\s)@<!` - location not immediately preced with a whitespace
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(\s{2,})?` - an optional occurrence of two or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of line
- `g` - all occurrences on the line.

This is [how this regex works](https://regex101.com/r/GyxvOQ/1) (translated into PCRE).

Answer (score 0):

(This really should be a comment but formatting is important, here)

How do you want the following snippet to look after you have "fixed" it (spaces marked with `_`)?

```
First line, without trailing spaces
Second line, with one trailing space_
Third line, with two trailing spaces__
Fourth line, with more than two trailing spaces______
```

Comment: only the third line would have spaces at the end. It would have two spaces (__).
Lines 2 and 4 would not have any spaces at the end.